# How to Set Fixed Header for asp grid with Vertical and Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: html, css, asp.net

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36251/Gridview-Fixed-Headers

Referred the above link but Getting "Invalid Property Value" Issue for the TOP attribute in css

```
top: expression(document.getElementById("divgrid").scrollTop-2);
```